# Does Mederma for scar removal really work?

Tags: dermatology

I've heard both good and bad things about [Mederma](http://smile.amazon.com/Mederma-Skin-Care-Scars-1-76/dp/B000052YOB/ref=sr_1_1_a_it?ie=UTF8&qid=1461280340&sr=8-1&keywords=mederma).

They claim to be the most recommended product (by doctors and pharmacists) for scar removal but my dermatologist said that there's no scientific study that supports them and that dermatologists usually don't recommend them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I found they may have some benfit on the appearance of scars. But the info available is contradictory.

---

It is featured in a article on [ncbi.nlh.nih.org](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/9875187) called: Snake oil for the 21st century

[Effect of Mederma on hypertrophic scarring in the rabbit ear model](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/12087249)

- Improvement in dermal organization of collagen
- No significant difference in dermal vascularity or inflammation

> Computer analysis of the scar photographs demonstrated no significant
>   reduction in scar erythema with Mederma treatment

[A New Proprietary Onion Extract Gel Improves the Appearance of New Scars](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3390235/#__abstractid192172title)

> once-daily application of the proprietary advanced formulation of
>   onion extract gel is safe for use on new scars and significantly
>   improves their overall appearance, redness, softness, and smoothness
>   compared to control scars.

[Hypertrophic Scarring and Keloids: Pathomechanisms and Current and Emerging Treatment Strategies](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3022978/#__abstractid954756title)

- States that available data is contradictory

[A comprehensive evidence-based review on the role of topicals and dressings in the management of skin scarring](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4506744/#Abs1title)

> Two randomised studies by Draelos in 2008 (n = 60) and 2012 (n = 44),
>   following shave excision of seborrheic keratoses, concluded that
>   Mederma® improved the appearance, signs and symptoms of the healed
>   wounds compared with untreated controls [42, 43]; however, both these
>   studies note that funding was provided by the manufacturer Merz
>   Pharmaceuticals.

As for the Amazon product I cannot find where it was sponsored or approved for safety.

Comment: Thanks for the good links! I'm surprised at how contradictory the studies are.

In the Amazon article, the company claims:
“More doctors and pharmacists recommended Mederma than any other brand for older and newer scars"

Comment: @Scientist256 A lot of stuff says that, but unless you have studies and people to support that that's true. It means nothing.

Comment: It's surprising what companies can claim for over-the-counter medications like Mederma. The FDA should try to regulate this more. @Pobrecita